# How to get "this.value" on jQuery.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm writing the javascript on FireFox 11 with a text editor. In the follow case, "var n=this.val" becomes "undefined". How to get the local value in the original class object?

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var Test = {
    val : 0,
    begin: function(v){
        this.val = v;
        this.recieve();
    },
    complete: function(o){
        var n = this.val;   // undefined
    },
    recieve : function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : "http://www.yahoo.com/",  // Dummy
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            complete: this.complete,
            timeout: 1000,
        });
    },
};

var c = Object(Test);
c.begin(10);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `complete` is a callback the scope has changed and `this` doesn't refers to the object called `Test`. You only need to replace `this` with `Test` in the `complete` function:

```
    var n = Test.val;
```

=== UPDATE ===

Your question was "How to get the local value in the original class object?". My answer shows you how to get the field of your *static object*.

If you need a *shared object* you should change the structure to:

```
function Test() {
    var self = this;
    this.begin = function(v) {
        this.val = v;
        this.recieve();
    }
    this.complete = function(o) {
        var n = this.val;
    }
    this.recieve = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "http://www.yahoo.com/",  // Dummy
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function(data) {
                self.complete(data);
            },
            timeout: 1000,
        });
    }
}
```

Now you can create two different objects:

```
var c2 = new Test2;
c2.begin(10);
var d2 = new Test2;
d2.begin(20);
```

Comment: In this case, Test.val will be overwritten. var c = Object(Test); c.begin(10); var d = Object(Test); d.begin(20);

Answer (score 1):

`complete: this.complete.`**`bind(this)`**

This won't work in old IE versions, but with some effort (adding `es5 shim` code) one can make it working even there.

`complete` function is executed in context of ajax request. If you write such code:

```
var method = Test.complete;
method();
```

`this` is not preserved, you just get the link to the function.
`name1.name2()` has a trick in js. Not only `name2` should be a property of `name1` and be a function, but it (name2) is also executed in context of `name1`.

```
var x = 'outer', b = {
    x: 'inner',
    a: function() { return this.x; }
};
[(b.a)(), (m = b.a)()] // ["inner", "outer"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside complete handler `this` is not `Test`. Common solution is to create a proxy variable for it.

```
recieve : function(){
    var proxy = this;
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://www.yahoo.com/",  // Dummy
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function(){
              proxy.complete();
        },
        timeout: 1000,
    });
},
```

or ( in this case ) simply `Test.val` inside function `complete`

```
complete: function(o){
    var n = Test.val;   
},
```